# Is there a way to unbind events bound with CrossriderAPI.bindExtensionEvent?

Tags: jquery, crossrider

I'd like to be able to unbind some events I bind using CrossriderAPI.bindExtensionEvent.  Anyone know if this is possible?

```
CrossriderAPI.bindExtensionEvent(document.body, 'eventName', function (e, result) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, CrossriderAPI does not provide a method for removing an event listener added using [CrossriderAPI.bindExtensionEvent](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/CrossriderAPI.events-method-bindExtensionEvent). The events are ultimately added using native browser event listeners so you can try using them to remove the events. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]